# Reversing a String: Is this O(log n) time complexity?

Tags: python, string, algorithm, time-complexity, reverse

I was doing [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-integer/) leetcode question which asks to reverse an integer. I wrote this method to convert int to string and reverse using divide-and-conquer recursion technique. I want to know is this **O(log n)** time complexity? (**n** being the number of characters in String).

```
def __reverse_recur__(self, num: str):
    N = len(num)
    # if we are reduced to only a single char, return it
    if N == 1:
        return num
    else:
        n = int(N / 2)  # index to split string from middle
        
        # concatenate the recursion result as follows:
        # recurse on the right-part of the string to place it as the left half of the concatenation
        left_half = self.__reverse_recur__(num[n:])
        # recurse on the left-part of the string to place it as the right half of the concatenation
        right_half = self.__reverse_recur__(num[:n])

        # return the concatenated string
        return left_half + right_half
```

Comment: Reversing a standard string (with no funny implementation) in O(log n) is a-priori impossible without analyzing any specific approach: O(log n) time is not enough to even look at the entire string

Comment: Just to speculate on the downvotes: on what grounds do you think it's O(log n)? What is your understanding of linear vs logarithmic complexity? A bit of research should lead one to check the complexity of slices, which are linear when they're based on `n`, as in `num[n:]`, which already makes O(log n) overall impossible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is ***O*(*n* log *n*)**.

String concatenation is linear. Each `+` in the expression `left_half + right_half` takes *O*(*l*+*r*) time, where *l* = `len(left_half)` and *r* = `len(right_half)`.

- You concatenate two length *n*/2 strings 1 time.
- You concatenate two length *n*/4 strings 2 times.
- You concatenate two length *n*/8 strings 4 times.
- ...
- You concatenate two length 4 strings *n*/8 times.
- You concatenate two length 2 strings *n*/4 times.
- You concatenate two length 1 strings *n*/2 times.

Each step takes *O*(*n*) and there are *O*(log *n*) steps, leading to an overall time complexity of *O*(*n* log *n*).

<sub>Footnote: The string slices `num[n:]` and `num[:n]` also have linear complexity. Creating a slice of length *k* is *O*(*k*). Accounting for these costs doesn't change the overall analysis.</sub>